# After successful dockerfile build, apt-transport-https vanishes

Tags: docker, apt-get, apt

Over time I've assembled an untidy dockerfile for creating my dev environment and it generally works well. There are a couple of situations, though, where I install something during docker build and it seems to go well. But when I create a container, the program cannot be found.

Here are two lines from my dockerfile:

RUN `apt-get install -y apt-transport-https`

RUN `apt-get update && apt-get install -y heroku`

the dockerfile builds and the containers launch fine. heroku, which needed apt-transport-https to install, works fine, but when I try to run apt-transport-https from within my running container, it can't be found.

I thought it might be a path problem but when I search for apt-transport-https with "find / -type f -name apt-transport-https", it's not present anywhere

so my questions are:

1. why would apt-transport-https not be present when I create a container?
2. how do I ensure that it is present?

Answer (score 1):

`apt-transport-https` enables `apt` to fetch packages via https. So it's not executed directly, but apt uses it for https-connections.

https://packages.debian.org/en/jessie/apt-transport-https

You can find the package in your container via:

```
dpkg -l | grep apt-transport-https
```

or

```
apt list --installed | grep apt-transport-https
```